# merging array itself in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

My array looks like this:

```
{"type":"send","name":"kebab","quantity":"1"},
{"type":"send","name":"potato","quantity":"25000"},
{"type":"receive","name":"money","quantity":"1"},
{"type":"receive","name":"soul","quantity":"12"},
{"type":"receive","name":"paper","quantity":"8"},
{"type":"send","name":"kebab","quantity":"1"},
{"type":"send","name":"potato","quantity":"25000"},
{"type":"receive","name":"money","quantity":"1"},
{"type":"receive","name":"soul","quantity":"12"},
{"type":"receive","name":"paper","quantity":"8"}
```

I want it to merge into new array where the values would be added or subtracted, like this:

```
{"type":"send","name":"kebab","quantity":"2"},
{"type":"send","name":"potato","quantity":"50000"},
{"type":"receive","name":"money","quantity":"2"},
{"type":"receive","name":"soul","quantity":"24"},
{"type":"receive","name":"paper","quantity":"16"}
```

I can't figure it out how to do that

update: type and name should stay the same, only quantity would be changed

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the items down to a new array and add up the quantities.

```js
const items = [{"type":"send","name":"kebab","quantity":"1"},
{"type":"send","name":"potato","quantity":"25000"},
{"type":"receive","name":"money","quantity":"1"},
{"type":"receive","name":"soul","quantity":"12"},
{"type":"receive","name":"paper","quantity":"8"},
{"type":"send","name":"kebab","quantity":"1"},
{"type":"send","name":"potato","quantity":"25000"},
{"type":"receive","name":"money","quantity":"1"},
{"type":"receive","name":"soul","quantity":"12"},
{"type":"receive","name":"paper","quantity":"8"}]


let result = items.reduce((arr, item) => {
  // Find the item in the new array by name
  let found = arr.find(i => i.name == item.name && i.type == item.type)
  // If the item doesn't exist add it to the array
  if(!found) return arr.concat(item)
  // If the item does exist add the two quantities together
  // This will modify the value in place, so we don't need to re-add it
  found.quantity = parseFloat(item.quantity) + parseFloat(found.quantity)
  // Return the new state of the array
  return arr;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: May I ask why did you care to downvote? If you want to spend some reputation there are plenty of awful answers out there.

Comment: Yeah, me too. The results are the exact same as the provided desired result.

Comment: `1 * +1 == 5 * -1` ;) I think they don't want people to answer a question where the original poster hasn't shown any effort...

Comment: If that is true, they should down vote the question not answers.

Comment: I think they do both, to force the users to delete their post

Comment: @Ivan Well I did try to find a way to do it for like 5 hours now, my programming is beginners level, most topics on google I could find was merging 2 arrays into one, I tried different kind of loops to detach and reattach, I just can't make it work.

Comment: @Nova, all right, next time try to put the code you've tried even if it doesn't work. It will prevent those nasty downvoters from ruining the fun. By the way, did you find the answer you were looking for with those two replies?

Comment: @Ivan yes the code above is what I needed, though even with the comments I still have no clue how it works... ;) maybe some day

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` to group the array into an object. Use `Object.values` to convert the object into an array.

```js
var arr = [{"type":"send","name":"kebab","quantity":"1"},{"type":"send","name":"potato","quantity":"25000"},{"type":"receive","name":"money","quantity":"1"},{"type":"receive","name":"soul","quantity":"12"},{"type":"receive","name":"paper","quantity":"8"},{"type":"send","name":"kebab","quantity":"1"},{"type":"send","name":"potato","quantity":"25000"},{"type":"receive","name":"money","quantity":"1"},{"type":"receive","name":"soul","quantity":"12"},{"type":"receive","name":"paper","quantity":"8"}];

var result = Object.values(arr.reduce((c, v) => {
  c[v.name] = c[v.name] || {type: "",name: v.name,quantity: 0};
  c[v.name].quantity += +v.quantity;   //Update the quantity
  c[v.name].type = v.type;             //Update the type
  return c;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It baffles me too :) @Ivan

Comment: There are some users who think it's a good idea to downvote correct answers because they didn't like the question... @Ivan Use your upvote to revert that bad behavior and to indicate correct answers.